# How can I determine non-technical information about a company I'm about to be interviewed by?

Tags: job-search, company

This company - which is large-ish, not huge but probably with over 100 employees (maybe over 1,000, I can't say) - is trying to recruit me. They're not one of the central players in my field. I want to find out more about the company - but its website is essentially a marketing pitch and has little useful information.

Specificaly, I want to try and figure out information such as:

- Ownership structure
- Overall number of employees, hopefully categorized (R&D, sales, management, technical support staff, non-technical support staff etc.)
- Key technical/organziational decisions over the past several years
- Main technical partners and clients
- Annual revenues, hopefully categorized
- Annual expenses, hopefully categorized
- Debts/loans
- Hard strategic commitments by the company (e.g. signed a contract promising to do something within so many years; is building facilities at a different location)
- Sites at which it is active around the world and what happens at which site?

Note I'm *not* asking about determining personal information or anything technical with respect to the company's actual business.

How should I go about doing this? (Other than asking the people interviewing me and Googling, I mean)

Comment: @MisterPositive: I should have clarified I did some Googling and did not find most of what I was looking for, but it's a fair comment.

Comment: If this is a US publicly traded company, a Google should have pulled up the information your looking for, or at least a link to it.

Comment: @MisterPositive: In my case I have found out it is "privately owned"; but the question as it stands is general. So +1 for your comment.

Comment: If the company is privately owned, you are at the mercy of the company and what they have shared via press releases or at the corporate website.  You may want to look at GlassDoor Company reviews too.

Comment: At my company, most of this would be confidential information that would never be shared with someone who didn't work there.

Comment: What country is this for?

Comment: @Midas: The question is general, so try to generalize your answer. In my particular case it's the USA (although that's not really a country per se).

Comment: @einpoklum that doesn't really work. Where I would go to look up information about a company in Germany, compared to the UK, is completely different.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a public company I would suggest looking at their tax information. Notably the most recent 10k form. It should have information on budgets and money allocation at the very least.

Comment: 1. By "public" I assume you mean "traded in publicly-accessible stock exchanges", right? 2. How do I determine whether it's "public"? 3. How can I access their tax information?

Comment: You can search for it on the SEC Website.

Comment: @einpoklum - Yes, that is what is meant by a "public company" - short for "publicly traded."  Depending on the country/countries their stock is traded in (and by that I mean what exchanges they are part of), they have to file quarterly and annual reports with most of this information in it.  Also check out the investor relations section of their website.  You'll have to learn a little bit about these, but it's worth the time.  In particular, pay attention to EBITDA and any pending litigation for overall company health.  Obviously for smaller, privately held companies, this isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Go to their website and get all the public releases there.

The wall street Journal, Barons, and other financial sites should have information on them.

All the information is out there on line, and GIYF (Google is your friend)

Comment: +1 only about the WSJ and Barons suggestions; their website is obvious (and unfortunately not useful).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention the country, I assume you are in the United Kingdom. You'll find tons of information about the company at the website http://companieshouse.gov.uk , whether they are a private or publicly held British company. And the information that you don't find gives you very strong hints as well. Like if they haven't filed their accounts for the last 18 months, then you won't get their accounts for that time, but the fact they didn't file is useful information in itself.

Comment: I suppose that's useful if I were in the UK (which I'm not); thanks.

Comment: Well, that happens when you leave out essential information in your question. And answers are not just for you but for others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a privately owned company, then you will probably have to talk to someone at the company to find these things out. You said you're being recruited; can you meet with the person recruiting you and ask them these questions? They probably won't know all the details offhand, but they can give you a general idea of the answers and get further details to you later.

Also, some of those things you're looking for might be considered confidential. For instance, the company I work for would never, ever tell a prospective employee who our clients are. Even when we've decided to hire someone, they don't get told that until they officially start and sign nondisclosure agreements. I suggest you think of ways to get the information you're after in a more general sense, in case they won't give you specifics.